# Extract array to JSON

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a query that extracts a document with a username and password as a filter. My return value is an array (It will return the elements in phoneBook). How do I turn this into a JSON object? Just returning a JSON from a query would be ideal.

```
 db.users.find({userName:"mark", passWord:"test1234"}, {phoneBook:1,_id:0})
{ "phoneBook" : [   {   "firstName" : "Rupert",     "lastName" : "Styx", "phoneNumber" : "9147388152",  "email" : "ruperstyx@gmail.com" } ] }
```

I'm still playing around with this string. I can't extract the attributes inside of phoneBook and turn it into a JSON

Answer (score 0):

If you use php then you can use **jsonencode($your_array)** function for converting an array into json object and if you working on other language then just search function for converting an array into json.

Answer (score 0):

This is snipt from my code (my app in Node.js)

```
collection.find({
    "word": req.query.word
}).toArray(function(err, results) {
    var res = JSON.stringify(results);
});
```

Simply use `JSON.stringify(results)`

I hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

By using Robomongo tool you will be able to see query results in list, table and json view![image]

Answer (score 0):

Using robomongo:

```
db.getCollection('ModelName')
.find({})
.limit(20)
.map(function(model){
    return model.toSource()
})
```